# Word order for "Why do all German words sound the same?"

Tags: grammar, sentence, word-order

"Why do all German words sound the same?" What is the correct word order to say that?

1. なぜドイツ語の単語はすべて同じに聞こえるのか？ [Naze doitsugo no tango wa subete onaji ni kikoeru nodesu ka?]
2. なぜすべてのドイツ語の単語は同じに聞こえるのか? [Naze subete no doitsugo no tango wa onaji ni kikoeru no ka?]

Or is there another way to say it?

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are okay and natural. In Sentence 1, すべて is used adverbially, and that's the primary way to express the number/amount of something in Japanese, especially in casual speech. This has been discussed several times:

- [How to list numbers of things](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5010)
- [Questions about counters](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36890/5010)
- [たくさんの本を読んで versus 本をたくさん読んで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27483/5010)
- [Counters and their placements with nouns](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80368/5010)
- [Positioning of quantities (using counters)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8136/5010)

So if I have to choose one, Sentence 1 sounds more common to me. In this case, however, the sentence ends with a literary question marker のか, making it look technical, like the title of an written article. In such a case, Sentence 2 does not sound unnatural at all to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think your first sentence sounds more natural. I would tweek it slightly though (in bold).

なぜドイツ語の単語**が**すべて同じ**ように**聞こえるのか？

Also, there isn't anything necessarily wrong with it, but I feel like it would be more natural to say 言葉 instead of 単語。That's probably just me though.

Comment: `なぜドイツ語の単語がすべて同じように聞こえるのか？` <- 「なぜドイツ語の単語はすべて同じに聞こえるのか？」でいいと思いますが・・・　 「なぜ空**は**青いのか？」「象の鼻**は**どうして長いの？」って言いますけど「なぜ空が青いのか？」「象の鼻がどうして長いの？」って、使い方がちょっと違いますよね（「なぜ空が青いのか、知っていますか？」のように使ったり。）「同じに聞こえる」「同じに見える」も普通に使いますし。